# Change stack size at runtime

Tags: java, memory

Can I change stack size at runtime for a particular thread?

**Explanation** : Can I have a situation where one thread stack has size say, 64kb and another say, 128kb? And further, Can this be achieved at runtime?

Comment: I'm pretty sure (but not certain) the answer is 'no'.  BTW - The **Explanation** above explains the What? but not the Why?.  ***Why*** do you think this is necessary for your app.?

Comment: This is not for my app, was preparing some presentation. This doubt just came across my mind. Googled it, but could not find much info. Just to clear some basic concept. :)

Comment: None of those words explains Why? to me.  Was that the intent of the words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change stack size for already created threads, but you can configure stack size for newly created thread - [there is special constructor for it.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread%28java.lang.ThreadGroup,%20java.lang.Runnable,%20java.lang.String,%20long%29) 
But be aware that such manipulations are considered to be platform dependent and that's why should be used as rarely as possible.